# Missing files in Yocto SDK

Tags: sdk, yocto, bitbake

I have some files downloaded by a certain recipe during an Yocto image build. I want to include them in the SDK of the same image.

I add this recipe in TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK.

When I build the SDK based on the my custom image(populate_sdk) these files are missing from the resulting SDK. I can see only some certain header files made for that particular recipe.

I want to know how I can include these files in the SDK build. I didn't find any commands that does that for files for SDKs.

For reference, the files are downloaded by the recipe from this git:
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/archive/3.6.zip

The Recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "DJI Onboard SDK"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE_FLAGS = "osdk"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PV = "3.6"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/archive/${PV}.zip"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/Onboard-SDK-${PV}:"  
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " osdk"

S="${WORKDIR}/Onboard-SDK-${PV}"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT  = "1"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

FILES_${PN} = "usr/lib/* usr/share/*"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "usr/include/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please:
 - Give us the recipe
 - Tell us how you have populated TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK variable ?

Should be something like that:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " <recipename>-staticdev"
```

Have you add (inside the recipe):

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

So we need more info to help you :)

Comment: I have updated the question with the recipe. Can you explain what the "-staticdev" suffix is for?

Comment: I'm not expert but you can find the info [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-building-an-sdk-installer)